# Magento 2 - dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api

Tags: magento2, composer

I try to update my packages via composer with `composer update` but I get this:

[image]

```
The "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.1.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
No composer.lock file present. Updating dependencies to latest instead of installing from lock file. See https://getcomposer.org/install for more information.
Loading composer repositories with package information
^Chausfux@rb-VirtualBox:/var/www/hausfux/m2$ bin/composer1 update
The "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.1.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
Loading composer repositories with package information
In Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterV2::onPrePoolCreate
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer ^0.5.0 -> satisfiable by dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer[v0.5.0].
    - dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
```

I also tried it with composer v2, but it does not work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@black - This issue will arise mainly because of incompatible composer version. You can downgrade the composer version and try running the commands.

Comment: You were right, I tried it with 1.10.23 and it worked !

Comment: Doing so does keep you stuck on composer v1. If you want to move to composer v2, what's the answer then?

Comment: Wouter, I fixed this changing the version from ¨0.5" to version ¨0.7¨:

"dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7",